# How to create a text file using Macro in MS Office?

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

I have word document. I want to create a text file when opening this document.
How can i create text file using macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You can create the text file in `Document_Open()` event

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    Dim filesize As Integer
    Dim FlName As String

    FlName = "C:\Sample.Txt"

    '~~> get a free file handle
    filesize = FreeFile()

    '~~> Open your file
    Open FlName For Output As #filesize

    '~~> Export Text
    Print #filesize, "Hello World"
    Close #filesize
End Sub
```